# Install Google Earth on Linux Fedora (rpm)

Tags: linux, centos, centos-7, google-earth

I'm trying to install [Google Earth](http://www.google.com/earth/):

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core) 
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ uname -a
Linux wcmisdlin02.uftmasterad.org 3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 27 03:04:26 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ sudo yum install ~/Downloads/google-earth-stable_current_x86_64.rpm 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Examining /home/alexus/Downloads/google-earth-stable_current_x86_64.rpm: google-earth-stable-7.1.4.1529-0.x86_64
Marking /home/alexus/Downloads/google-earth-stable_current_x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-earth-stable.x86_64 0:7.1.4.1529-0 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================
 Package                  Arch        Version            Repository                                Size
========================================================================================================
Installing:
 google-earth-stable      x86_64      7.1.4.1529-0       /google-earth-stable_current_x86_64      194 M

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 194 M
Installed size: 194 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin from install of google-earth-stable-7.1.4.1529-0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-18.el7.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------

[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ rpm -q filesystem
filesystem-3.2-18.el7.x86_64
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ yum info filesystem
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: mirror.cs.vt.edu
 * updates: centos.mirror.nac.net
Installed Packages
Name        : filesystem
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 3.2
Release     : 18.el7
Size        : 0.0  
Repo        : installed
From repo   : anaconda
Summary     : The basic directory layout for a Linux system
URL         : https://fedorahosted.org/filesystem
License     : Public Domain
Description : The filesystem package is one of the basic packages that is installed
            : on a Linux system. Filesystem contains the basic directory layout
            : for a Linux operating system, including the correct permissions for
            : the directories.

[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$
```

... needless to say I *CANNOT* remove `filesystem` package, as that'd screw up my entire system ...

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had major issues using Google RPMs, and have started just taking the files out of them and copying them directly.

Here's my magic line:

```
rpm2cpio google-earth-stable_current_x86_64.rpm  | cpio -idmv
```

EDIT: Probably worth mentioning that yes, I do check for dependencies etc....

Comment: that worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

PER The Official Google Earth Forums --this also happens on RHEL & Fedora --for others with rpm issues: [Google Earth Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/G9o9bHuzXi8)

In a nutshell:   (Assumes  rpm-build installed and downloading from https://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_x86_64.rpm)

> user@centos7 $ rpmrebuild -d /tmp -ep google-earth-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
>
> Remove the line: %dir %attr(0755, root, root) "/usr/bin"
>
> Save and exit
>
> Answer yes
>
> root@Centos7# yum install /tmp/x86_64/local path to google earth package
>
> (optional)  ln -s /opt/google/...  /usr/bin

(or wherever you threw it if not /opt/google/.... as /opt/google/... is the normal location for google ware)